# what is the way to create local notification in iOS 10 . does it work in older iOS version?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

what is the way to create local notification in iOS 10?
**does it work in older iOS version?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift display local notification even the app terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50383851/swift-display-local-notification-even-the-app-terminated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `#available(iOS 10.0, *)` syntax to separate your logic for iOS 10.0+ or else. I am sure you can find a lot of answers in here.

[Local and Push Notifications in IOS version compatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688760/local-and-push-notifications-in-ios-version-compatible/42688966#42688966)

Comment: thanks calvin dear